# website doesn't load in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, web, loading

I am developping an educative website about electrocardiograms. It is working fine in chrome, firefox and opera but it doesnt even load on some computers on IE8. I cant figure out why. Any help appreciated.
Link to the website: -> [ECG Quiz](http://www.ecg-quiz.com)

Comment: IE 8 doesnot support CSS 3 ,so it doesnt apply styles.

Comment: Using a validator can help finding problems. A quick check showed 18 HTML and 544 CSS errors. HTML: http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ecg-quiz.com%2F CSS: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?profile=css21&warning=0&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ecg-quiz.com%2F

Answer (score 0):

Try adding website to the Trusted list in IE8.